# É possível o dono de uma resposta saber quem negativou sua resposta dada?

Tags: suporte, votos, voto-contra

Sou apenas um leigo, e estou compreendendo aos poucos o sistema do site Stack Overflow e Stack Overflow Meta. Fiquei a me perguntar se isso é possível, ao dono de uma resposta saber quem negativou sua resposta dada, em caso afirmativo, como?

Comment: Bom, conheço um esquema com a galera do banco de dados em NY, mas tipo vai lhe custar uma grana... te passo o valor e o numero da conta por mensagem privada, inclui minha comissão...  garantia 100%... qual a resposta mesmo? :P

Comment: @bfavaretto então se aconteceu do cara descobrir então foi na tentativa?

Comment: A pessoa pode suspeitar, inferir, mas não ter certeza. A não ser que quem votou diga que votou.

Comment: @Boa noite noite caras!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Não, isso não é possível, os votos são secretos.

Caso suspeite que um usuário esteja votando *sistematicamente* em você (ou em algum outro usuário), seja positiva ou negativamente, sinalize uma publicação envolvida e explique aos moderadores o que está acontecendo. Iremos analisar. Nós também não temos como saber quem deu os votos, mas temos ferramentas para detectar abusos. Em caso de dúvidas, falamos com o Gabe e ele pode verificar mais a fundo.

Comment: Não é possível em tese. Tem gente que tem experiência e consegue inferir os votos. Tem macetes que você não sabe c/ 100% de certeza, mas chega bem perto :) E se você suspeita que um usuário vai começar te negativar sistematicamente porque não gosta de você, sem avaliar o conteúdo? E a pessoa já negativou só porque era você e depois retirou o voto? :) O importante é que um espertinho que acha que pode burlar as regras do jogo, fazer como bem entende e se vingar de quem ele não gosta, não vai conseguir o intento e pode até acabar suspenso, certo?

Comment: @bigown Você trabalha com bola de cristal cara?

Comment: Eu tenho, pode acreditar e ela funciona muito bem. Eu sei quem deu quase todos os negativos que eu levo. Eu uso esse negócio há 7 anos e sei analisar os dados. Os votos não são mostrados, mas outras informações estão disponíveis, sabendo para quem você tem que olhar, o que tem que olhar e fazendo as contas certas, dá para saber com mais de 90% de certeza. O resto fica pela psicologia, você vê quem é que pode ter raiva de você e fazer uso errado da ferramenta para se vingar. Tem mais um motivo que eu sei, mas esse eu não revelo :D

Comment: @bigown parece uma teoria da conspiração :P